# QSqlQuery Not Executing When Using Table Variable

Tags: sql, sql-server, python-3.x, pyqt

I am using Python 3 and PyQt 5 to execute a query that includes a table variable. My other queries work, but this specific one is causing me issues. The query is:

```
declare @Temp table 
(
    SKU varchar(25), 
    Lines int
) 

insert into @Temp 
SELECT convert(varchar, [Sku]) as [SKU] 
    ,count([Order Number]) as [Lines] 
from [Database].dbo.[Table Name] 
GROUP BY [Sku] 
ORDER BY [LINES] 

Select RANK() OVER(Order by Lines Desc) / (Select Convert(float,Count(*)) from @Temp) as [CUM PERCENT SKU] 
    ,sum(Lines) Over(Order by Lines Desc) / convert(float,sum(Lines) Over()) as [CUM PERCENT LINES]
from @Temp 
Order By [Lines] DESC
```

I replaced the Database name and the Table name, but the rest of the text is the exact query.

Executing the above in SQL Server 2012 works perfectly. Is there a limitation to QSql that I don't know about?

Thank you in advance!

Comment: So what issues so you see when you execute it normally? That might help you get an answer.

Comment: It wasn't executing at all. When I called query.next(), it was false (no results).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After a bit more research, it turns out that you need to use prepare() when you are trying to create a table (apparently even a temporary one).

I'm posting the answer in case anyone else has the same issue and doesn't feel like going through the C++ StackOverflow answers.

```
query = QSqlQuery()
query.prepare(*query text here*)
query.exec_()
```